# Rename all xml files within a given directory with Python

Tags: python, file-rename

I have lot of xml files which are named like:

```
First_ExampleXML_Only_This_Should_Be_Name_20211234567+1234565.xml
Second_ExampleXML_OnlyThisShouldBeName_202156789+55684894.xml
Third_ExampleXML_Only_This_Should_Be_Name1_2021445678+6963696.xml
Fourth_ExampleXML_Only_This_Should_Be_Name2_20214567+696656.xml
```

I have to make a script that will go through all of the files and rename them, so only this is left from the example:

```
Only_This_Should_Be_Name.xml
OnlyThisShouldBeName.xml
Only_This_Should_Be_Name1xml
Only_This_Should_Be_Name2.xml
```

At the moment I have something like this but really struggling to get exactly what I need, guess that have to count from second _ up to _202, and take everything in between.

```
fnames = listdir('.')
for fname in fnames:
    # replace .xml with type of file you want this to have impact on
    if fname.endswith('.xml):
```

Anyone has idea what would be the best approach to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip the contents by splitting with underscores for all xml files and rename with the first value in the list as below.

```
import os

fnames = os.listdir('.')
for fname in fnames:
    # replace .xml with type of file you want this to have impact on
    if fname.endswith('.xml'):
        newName = '_'.join(fname.split("_")[2:-1])
        os.rename(fname, newName+".xml")
    else:
        continue
```

here you are eliminating the values which are before and after "_".

Comment: This cuts string in a wierd name,  I only get ExampleXML.xml after running

Comment: As you doesn't need only the last two parts you can try like above. basically you can join with underscore by removing prefix and sufix.

Comment: I have to keep everything from second _ up to _202, what would be regex for that?

Comment: simply you can append_202 as suffix

Comment: Man I am sorry but had to update names of files since now they are generated in this format. Please take a look now

Comment: Then you need to join from[2:-1] and I guess you don't need to have  '_202' as suffix

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237369/discussion-between-sangeerththan-balachandran-and-john).

Comment: Perfect, works!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

### Finding files of one kind in the directory

Whilst listdir will work, you might as well glob them:

```py
from pathlib import Path

for fn in Path("/path").glob("*.xml"):
    ....
```

### Renaming files

In this case your files are named "file_name_NUMBERS.xml" and we want to strip the numbers out, so we'll use a regex:  **Edit: this is not the best way in this case.  Just split and combine as in the other answer**

```py
import re
from pathlib import Path
for fn in Path("dir").glob("*.xml"):
    new_name = re.search(r"(.*?)_[0-9]+", fn.stem).group(1)
    fn.rename(fn.with_name(new_name + ".xml"))
```

**Edit:** don't know why I overcomplicted things.  I'll leave the `re` solution there for more difficult cases, but in this case you can just do:

```py
new_name = "_".join(fn.stem.split("_")[:-1])
```

Which is greately superior as it doesn't depend on the precise naming of the files.

Note that you can do all this without pathlib, but you asked for the *best* way ;)

Lastly, to answer an implicit question, nothing stops you wrapping all this in a function and passing an argument to glob for different types of files.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer mate! This is what I am looking for.. but when I execute I keep getting: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: In that case the regex isn't matching.  I suspect you have a file differently.

Comment: After your edit I tried again but got: AttributeError
'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I think I should go to lunch.  I meant fn.stem.  Incidentally I recommend reading the pathlib docs when you *start* learning python, rather than messing about with strings everywhere for ages.  But that might just be taste

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I had to update name of files cause they are now generated differently, please take a look

Comment: Any of the answers on here bar the re will work (and the re is easily updated).  See if you can get at *what* they are doing, and you will be able to adapt them to anything you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think regex will be the simplest approach here, which in python can be accomplished with the `re` module.

```py
import os
import re

fnames = os.listdir('.')
for fname in fnames:
    result = re.sub(r"^.*?_ExampleXML_(.*?)_[\d+]+\.xml$", r"\1.xml", fname)
    if result != fname:
       os.rename(fname, result)
```

There are several pattern matching strategies you could employ, depending on your use case.

For instance you could try variants like the following, depending on how specific/general you need to be:

- `^.*?_ExampleXML_(.*?)_\d+\.xml$` (https://regex101.com/r/hYOLMF/1)
- `^.*?_ExampleXML_(.*?)_2021\d+\.xml$` (https://regex101.com/r/UzEsbO/1)
- `^.*?_ExampleXML_(.*?)_[^_]+\.xml$` (https://regex101.com/r/lKzYhq/1)

Comment: Thanks mate! I keep getting error: TypeError
expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: But had to clue about this regex101, thanks!

Comment: Also I had to update name of files cause they are now generated differently, please take a look now, thanks!

Comment: @John updated. Are you using python3? I updated the regex to include the additional `+` symbol mixed in with your numbers.

Comment: yep, I managed to get solution, thanks man!